# An unknown issue when trying to print a Sub-string in Batch script

Tags: batch-file

So i was trying to create a batch script in order to automate a task in my system, doing so requires me to create a procedure that will allow me to print a string one character at a time so lets say my string is equal to "Hello" (without quotes) then the intended result is:

```
>test.bat Hello
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
```

And this is the code that i came up with:

```
@echo off
title test

set string=%1
set /A i=0

:print_str
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%string%"=="!string:~0,!i!!" (
    echo %string%
    endlocal
    goto eof
) else (
    echo !string:~0,!i!!
    set /A i+=1
    goto print_str
)

:eof
pause > nul
```

========================================================================

### What i think is the problem:

After i spent some time testing and trying to figure out what could possibly cause this issue i found out that the problem is in `!string:~0,!i!!` instruction and that it is not parsed in the way i assumed it would, i tried it the following code in order to get a better idea of the problem:

```
@echo off
title test1

set string=hello
set /A i=1

echo %string:~0,%i%%
pause > nul
```

and this was its output:

```
>test1.bat
%i
```

obviously that wasn't the output i expected i was expecting the sub string 'e'and that's how i came to the conclusion that what ever the problem is in the test.bat it has to do with the sub string instruction.

I tried many things like doubling the percentage mark (thinking it was similar to % and %% problem) enabling delayed expansions but without any success!

========================================================================

## Minimal code:

```
@echo off
title test

:print_str
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:eof
pause > nul
```

========================================================================

#### Algorithm:

The way i intended for it to work is as follow:

We initialize the index (variable i) to 0 and in each iteration if the stopping condition is not verified we print the current sub string ( it will have an equal amount of characters as the current value of the index) and then we increase the index by one and we repeat the process, the `if` statement is there to make sure that we do not exceed the strings length and also to avoid an infinite loop, by comparing the complete string to a sub-string of string, this sub string will change every time the index is different and will eventually be equal to string after a certain amount of iterations (when i will be equal to the length of string).

#### Problem and console output:

However it did not work as i expected it to, when i execute the script i always end up in an infinite loop that prints the following lines
     Maximum setlocal recursion level reached.
    i
    Maximum setlocal recursion level reached.
    i
    Maximum setlocal recursion level reached. 
    i
    .
    .
    .
    ans so on untril i kill the Job by hiting ctrl+c

## Questions:

1)-Can you please explain to me why i am getting this infinite loop ? and why is the output of `!string:~0,!i!!` just an i
2)-Please explain to me how to use the echo command with the `!string:~0,!i!!` when the length isn't a constant

any code suggestions we be deeply appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set string=%1
set /A i=1

:print_str
if "%string%"=="!string:~0,%i%!" (
    echo %string%
    endlocal
    goto ver2
) else (
    echo !string:~0,%i%!
    set /A i+=1
    goto print_str
)

:ver2
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO -------------------------------------
set "string=%1"
set /A i=0
:print_str2
SET /a i+=1
IF "!string:~%i%!" neq "" ECHO !string:~0,%i%!&GOTO print_str2
ECHO %string%


GOTO :EOF
```

Your fundamental problem is that`"!string:~0,!i!!"` is interpreted as `"!string:~0,!+i+!!"` (where `+` here means "concatenated with") which will never be equal to "%string%" hence the `else` part is perpetually executed, displaying the `i`.

Next problem is that `setlocal` is not a switch - it opens a frame that is closed by an `endlocal` or reaching end-of-file. The number of these frames is limited to 32.

With your code, the statements before the `setlocal` will set variables permanently in the environment for this instance of `cmd`. The result is that user-set variables clutter the environment. Hence, it is normal practice to use a `setlocal` as the command immediately following the initial `@echo off`.

Since `echo !string:~0,%i%!` will be parsed as `echo` should `i` be `0`, then that statement will report the `echo` status, hence `i` should be a minimum of `1`.

The statement `goto :eof` (the `:` is required here) is defined as going to the physical end of file. Declaring a user-label `:eof` is non-standard and confuses those who may maintain code.

Comment: Thank you for the bright explanations and the code (both version xD), as you may already know this does fix the problem i was having and again thank you for that, but there is two things that don't get yet: 1) why is the instruction ```"!string:~0,!i!!"``` interpreted as ```"!string:~0,!+i+!!"``` 2) in the second version of the solution i do not understand why you surrounded the ```string=%1``` with quotes, Thanks in advance

Comment: Second one's easy. That syntax ensures that any trailing spaces left on the line are not included into the value assigned to the variable. First one - when the `cmd` parser evaluates the string, it will do so left-to-right, character by character. Where it sees the sequence `%string%` or `!string!` or `%%character` it will replace those strings with the relevant value, then execute the assignment. So - using a simpler expression, `set v=!x!y!z!` with variables x,y,z having values `a`,`b`,`c` respectively, the result is `ayc`, not `the contents of (xbz)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i do understand how the parser works now thanks to your great explanation, also thank you for the "spaces tip" that is really handy, one last thing tho and sorry for not mentioning this in the my first comment because it is kinda related to it, you said in your answer that the instruction ```"!string:~0,!i!!"``` is interpreted as ```"!string:~0,!+i+!!"``` could you please explain to me why the + sign exactly ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be so much easier if we could use colours in comments. The `+` here means "these strings concatenated" - not a literal `+`. There are three strings, `!string:~0,!` and `i` and `!!` which evaluates to *emptystring* and i and *emptystring* and concatenating these three strings yields `i` which you observed was displayed.

Comment: Yeah colors would have made it much more easier, thank you again for your time and explanations i really appreciate your help, have a great day

Answer (score 1):

---

I prefer to use **`sep / p`** in **`Unicode`** instead of sub-string to get the same results, I will leave here a few options to do this for one or more arguments in the **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** files:

---

> - **Option #1** - only **1 loop**, **1 argument/parameter** ::
>
>   ---

[image]

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_arg=%~1" & title <nul & title .\%~nx0 test
echo/ & echo/ Option #1, argument/parameter %%~1

for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%s in ('echo/ ^&^& (
^<con: cmd/u/s/rset/p "=!_arg: .=.!"^<nul^|find /v ""^)
') do set "_str_=!_str_!%%s" && cmd /v /r echo[!_str_!

endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

---

> - **Option #2** - only **1 loop**, **many arguments/parameters** ::
>
>   ---

[image]

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

title <nul & title .\%~nx0 Test
set "_p=call "%__AAPDIR__%pathping.exe" 127.1 -n 1 -q 1 -p 500"
for /f "skip=4delims= " %%a in ('echo prompt $h^|cmd')do set "_bs=%%~a"

echo/ & echo/ Option #2, many argument/parameter %%~*
for %%a in (%*)do set "_arg=%%a" && for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%s in ('
echo/ ^&^& (^<con: cmd/u/r set/p "=!_arg: .=.!"^<nul^|find /v ""
^)')do set "_str_=!_str_!%%s" && cmd /v /r echo[!_str_!

endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

---

> - **Option #3** - now **2 loopings**, **1 argument/parameter** ::
>
>   ---

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

title <nul & title .\%~nx0 Test 

set "_p="%__AAPDIR__%pathping.exe" 127.1 -n 1 -q 1 -p 250"
for /f "skip=4delims= " %%a in ('echo prompt $h^|cmd')do set "_bs=%%~a"

echo/ & echo/ Option #3, only argument/parameter %%~1 && set "_arg=%~1" 
for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%S in ('^<con: cmd/u/s/rset/p "=!_arg!"^<nul^|find /v ""
')do set "_str=!_str!%%S" && echo/ && for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%a in ('
^<con: cmd /v/u/e/s/r set/p "=!_str: .=.!"^<nul^|find /v ""
')do >nul call !_p! & set /p "'=^|!_bs!%%a"<nul
echo/ & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

---

> - **Option #4** - now **2 loopings**, **many arguments/parameters** ::
>
>   ---

[image]

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

title <nul & title .\%~nx0 Test 

set "_p="%__AAPDIR__%pathping.exe" 127.1 -n 1 -q 1 -p 250"
for /f "skip=4delims= " %%a in ('echo prompt $h^|cmd')do set "_bs=%%~a"

echo/ & echo/ Option #4, any argument/parameter %%~* 
for %%A in (%*)do set "_arg=%%A" && (for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%S in ('
echo/ ^&^& ^<con: cmd/u/s/rset/p "=!_arg!"^<nul^|find /v ""
')do set "_str=!_str!%%S" && echo/ && for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%a in ('
^<con: cmd /v/u/e/s/r set/p "=!_str: .=.!"^<nul^|find /v ""
')do >nul call !_p! & set /p "'=^|!_bs!%%a"<nul )
echo/ & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

---

> - **Option #5** - now **1 looping & 1 write 1 line**, **1 argument/parameter** ::
>
>   ---

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

title <nul & title .\%~nx0 Test 

set "_p="%__AAPDIR__%pathping.exe" 127.1 -n 1 -q 1 -p 250"
for /f "skip=4delims= " %%a in ('echo prompt $h^|cmd')do set "_bs=%%~a"

echo/ & echo/ Option #5, argument/parameter %%~1 & echo/
set "_arg=%~1" && for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%a in ('echo/ ^&^& (
^<con: cmd /v/u/e/s/r set/p "=!_arg: .=.!"^<nul^|find /v ""
^)')do >nul call !_p! & set /p "'=^|!_bs!%%a"<nul
echo/ & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

> - **Option #5** - now **1 looping & 1 write 1 line**, **1 argument/parameter** ::
>
>   ---

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

title <nul & title .\%~nx0 Test 

set "_p="%__AAPDIR__%pathping.exe" 127.1 -n 1 -q 1 -p 250"
for /f "skip=4delims= " %%a in ('echo prompt $h^|cmd')do set "_bs=%%~a"

echo/ & echo/ Option #5, argument/parameter %%~1 & echo/
set "_arg=%~1" && for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%a in ('echo/ ^&^& (
^<con: cmd /v/u/e/s/r set/p "=!_arg: .=.!"^<nul^|find /v ""
^)')do >nul call !_p! & set /p "'=^|!_bs!%%a"<nul
echo/ & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

> - **Option #6** - now **1 looping & 1 write 1 line**, **many argument/parameter** ::
>
>   ---

[image: ![![enter image description here]

---

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

title <nul & title .\%~nx0 Test 

set "_p="%__AAPDIR__%pathping.exe" 127.1 -n 1 -q 1 -p 250"
for /f "skip=4delims= " %%a in ('echo prompt $h^|cmd')do set "_bs=%%~a"

echo/ & echo/ Option #6, 1 line many arguments/parameters %%~1 & echo/
for %%A in (%*)do set "_arg=%%A" && for /f ^delims^=^ eol^=* %%a in ('
echo/ ^&^& (^<con: cmd /v/u/e/s/r set/p "=!_arg: .=.!"^<nul^|find /v ""
^)')do >nul call !_p! & set /p "'=^|!_bs!%%a"<nul
echo/ & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

---